# Content on firefox not showing up on flash, help needed on flash scripts?

Tags: flash, firefox, compatibility

This is my site:
http://johnnathankorver.com/

If you click on content menus you may notice that content comes in for a while then it hides.
It happens only in firefox. Works ok on IE.

This is my button script when someone clicks on one of the menu, please let me know if theres something wrong with my code:

```
on (rollOver)
{
if (_root.page != 2)
{
_root.menu.about.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
}
on (rollOut, releaseOutside)
{
if (_root.page != 2)
{
_root.menu.about.gotoAndPlay(10);
}
}
on (release)
{
if (_root.page != 2 & _root.y != 0)
{
_root.galler.play();
_root.pic = 22;
_root.poy.play();
_root.page = 2;
_root.menu.about.a.play();
if (_root.a == 1)
{
_root.menu.main.gotoAndPlay(10);
_root.menu.main.a.play();
}
if (_root.a == 2)
{
_root.menu.about.gotoAndPlay(10);
_root.menu.about.a.play();
}
if (_root.a == 3)
{
_root.menu.gall.gotoAndPlay(10);
_root.menu.gall.a.play();
}
if (_root.a == 4)
{
_root.menu.arch.gotoAndPlay(10);
_root.menu.arch.a.play();
}
if (_root.a == 5)
{
_root.menu.cont.gotoAndPlay(10);
_root.menu.cont.a.play();
}
_root.a = 2;
}
}
```

Regards
Sukhu
Flash Developer

Answer (score 0):

Check your publish settings and check players version, also if you have tweens with in your script sometimes they may error out because you pressed a btn before the tween has finished.To avoid this problem I suggest using 3rd party library's "greensock" tweenligh/tweenMax

Try doing this in AS3, easier and more efficient. the move to switch is quiet easy eitherway you will have to learn it anyways, Also if have this file published to a server let us look at it i may have a better idea whats goin on, hard to guess but i dont know what contents/assets are missing

Also is it embedded in HTML/ or PHP sometimes that causes issues if your method is incorrect
Check google for more info regards to embedding flash into different browsers, i have had this issue in the past "internet Explorer vs Firefox"!

By the way your code appears fine.